# Search the weird array for exact match

Tags: javascript

We have an array like this:

```
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
```

The `=` is just a separator and separates `first string` from the second: `string A = string B`

And we have a string variable like this one:

```
let mainSt = 'i was sent';
```

What if we want to search the `first strings` of `trapSt` and compare them to `mainSt` and return the result?

- If there is an **Exact Match** return the `trapSt` element like `"i was sent = i sent"`
- If there is not an **Exact Match** return `false`

Note:

- it seems that `indexOf()` and `includes()` doesn't handle Exact Match.
- I know how to search the whole `trapSt`, What I don't know is how could we search only the `first strings`!

UPDATE:

```js
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
let mainSt = 'i was sent';

console.log(trapSt.map(e => e.indexOf(mainSt)));
console.log(trapSt.map(e => e.includes(mainSt)));
```

Comment: I have added the update Exact Match and searching only the first strings are my problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let findTrap = str => {
  let traps = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
  let trapPairs = traps.map(s => s.split(' = '));
  let matchI = trapPairs.findIndex(([first]) => first === str);
  return traps[matchI] || false;
}

console.log(findTrap('i was sent'));
console.log(findTrap('to protect you'));
console.log(findTrap('foo'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` rather than `map()`. It returns the element that matches the condition, instead of an array of the conditions.

You should also use `startsWith()` rather than `includes`, so you only check the first part. And append `=` to ensure that it matches the whole first part.

```js
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
let mainSt = 'i was sent';

console.log(trapSt.find(e => e.startsWith(mainSt + " = ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.map` the array of strings to get only the first part with a simple `.split`, then you can iterate over the resulting strings to see if one of them matches what you want.

```js
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
let mainSt = 'i was sent';

let firstStrings = trapSt.map(x => x.split(" = ")[0].trim())

for (let i = 0; i < firstStrings.length; i++) {
  if (firstStrings[i] == mainSt) {
    console.log(trapSt[i], "Matches on index: "+i)
  }
  else{
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

This is a kind of pseudo-code, you can do better what you want as return by modifying the code above, but of course you can have a good idea of logic on how to find the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and check against the wanted string.

```js
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];
let mainSt = 'i was sent';

console.log(trapSt.map(s => s.split(' = ')[0] === mainSt && mainSt));
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Use a loop to iterate over the array

2)Use `substring(0,trapSt[i].indexOf("=")-1)` to get the first string

3)Match your search string with the substring you got in step 2, using `includes` or `indexOf`. If it matches, save the index of the loop

4)Use the index of the loop to get the whole string and return `trapSt[resIndex]`

Code:

```
let i = 0;
let mainSt = 'i was sent';
while (i < trapSt.length){
  let firstSt = substring(0,trapSt[i].indexOf("=")-1);
  if (firstSt.indexOf(mainSt)!==-1){
    return trapSt[i];
  }
  i = i+1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use map like in your example, then you can do this:

```
console.log(trapSt.map(e => e.substring(0,e.indexOf("=")-1).indexOf(mainSt)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Regex as an symply option

```
let trapSt = ["i was sent = i sent", "to protect you = to find you"];

let mainSt = 'i was sent';

let regex = new RegExp(`^(${mainSt}) ?=`);

let result = trapSt.map(t => {
  let match = t.match(regex);
  return match && match[0] && t.replace(match[0], '');
})
.find(r => !!r);

console.log(result);
```

I prepared the working sample for you:

[Sample in codepen](https://codepen.io/edmret/pen/povKamG)